# Keeping a value when i call a function inside a function?

Tags: python

Given a list, i'm trying to get a random change of two elements. I defined a function dosopt() that does that. Then, I call this function from another function named test(). So in this function "test" i tried to copy the initial argument in the variable x. Then I want to apply de function dosopt() on the variable "v", so it generates the same list "x" but with the interchange of two elements. The thing is that when I do that, the value of x also changes. 
I'm not very good at programming so a little bit of help would be nice

```
from random import randint
import copy as c

def test(other):
    x=other[:]
    v=dosopt(x)
    return x,v

def dosopt(solution):
    change=[]
    x=0
    while x!=1:
        i=randint(0,len(solution[0])-2)
        j=randint(0,len(solution[0])-2)
        if i!=j and i!=j+1 and j!=i+1:
            x=1
    if i<j:
        a=solution[0][i]
        b=solution[0][i+1]
        c=solution[0][j]
        d=solution[0][j+1]
        pos=[0,j,b,c]
        change.append(pos[:])
        solution[0][i+1]=change[0][3]
        solution[0][change[0][1]]=change[0][2]
    elif i>j:
        a=solution[0][j]
        b=solution[0][j+1]
        c=solution[0][i]
        d=solution[0][i+1]
        pos=[0,i,b,c]
        change.append(pos[:])
        solution[0][j+1]=change[0][3]
        solution[0][change[0][1]]=change[0][2]
    return(solution)

lis=[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0]]
```

As I can tell, the problem is on the function dosopt because i don't have this problem with other function.

Please ignore the meaningless lines of code, they come from a previous code.

Comment: Please remove meaningless lines of code from the question.

Comment: usually you either use a class for this and make either the seed value or the list an attribute of the class... or return it as part of the functions return value

Comment: trim your code so it's easier to understand: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because lists are copied by reference instead of copied by value.

Easiest way to get around this is to use the `copy` module.

```
import copy

my_list  = ["a", "b", "c"]
same_list = my_list
new_list = copy.deepcopy(my_list)

same_list[0] = "test"
my_list[1] = "something"
new_list[0] = "hello"

print(my_list)
print(same_list)
print(new_list)
```

results in

```
['test', 'something', 'c']
['test', 'something', 'c']
['hello', 'b', 'c']
```

So in your case if you want to copy `x` and save it you should use `v = dosopt(copy.deepcopy(x))`. You should be aware though that this could potentially be very slow depending on how big `x` is.

Also you are shadowing your import of `copy as c` when you use the variable `c` later. You should avoid doing this. Plus, `copy` isn't a long or complicated name so you shouldn't be aliasing it. Aliasing is typically reserved for when things are tedious to type or take up a ton of room on screen such as `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.